# Why is my spring-boot application build up memory over time?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot application that is using Spring Integration. The application pulls messages from a RabbitMQ queue, transforms the data from that message, aggregates 50 transformed messages, put those messages in array and sends them to a RESTful endpoint as JSON. I am seeing memory slowly creeps up until the application crashes.

I ran a profiler on our application and there are instances of VariableLinkedBlockingQueue building up over time. The application seems to clean them up after the application starts, but after some time, the application will just build up these instances. I forced a full garbage collection through the profiler on my application and it cleaned up some instances, but they continue to build up. These instances only go up while messages are being sent to the queue. The prefetch is set to 50.

Why am I seeing these instances build up and how do I fix this?

Comment: Would be very helpful to some simple Boot application to play from our side. Thanks

Comment: From my experience, it is mostly caused by memory leak in application itself, not underlying framework. Did you profile your memory?

Comment: I mentioned in the description that I ran a profiler on my application. There were instances that kept building up over time. The instances were com.rabbitmq.client.impl.VariableLinkedBlockingQueue<E>. I am unsure where these instances are coming from. After researching it, all I can guess is that these are instances build for incoming messages from rabbit. It seems thread related because linked blocking queues are used in the Java concurrency library. I'm not exactly sure though.

Answer (score 0):

`com.rabbitmq.client.impl.WorkPool` utilizes that `VariableLinkedBlockingQueue` and its logic is based on the register/unregister `Channel` as a client.

If you close `Channel`s properly, they are unregistered from that pool and therefore their `VariableLinkedBlockingQueue` is garbage collected.

Not having your application to see and play is very difficult to determine where is the leak.

Spring Integration AMQP support exists already for a while and if there was such a problem do not close channel, we'd know that already.

Right now it looks like you use `ConnectionFactory` somehow out of the box and don't close channels/connections after usage.